# How to add a numbered prefix on each line in JTextArea

Tags: java, list, jtextarea

I am trying to make a program that automatically adds a set prefix on each line inputted in the JTextArea

So let's say the prefix I set in code is "Step (#):", every line would be something like:
Step 1: test item
Step 2: test item 2
Step 3: test item 3

where the test items are inputted by the user. Preferrably the prefix is uneditable. Also curious if it was possible to automatically change the step number below incase a user makes a line break between steps.

I have tried appending the step but cant figure out how to add step 2 on line break or even auto adjust. Also tried DocumentFilter but got nowhere with it.

Comment: Then why not use an additional `JComponent` side-by-side of the editable one?

Comment: or print line by line and use String concatenation to add the  number to the front of the line

Comment: Instead of a single `JTextArea`, I'd use a `JList` and list individual `JPanels` consisting of an edit disabled `JTextField` for the prefix and a `JTextArea` for the task.  Yes, this is more complicated to set up but more flexible.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: Perhaps use Rob Camik's (@camikr) [TextLineNumber class](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/).